# Jinput library not found in java.library.path

Tags: java, jinput

I am trying to use jinput with a wrapper library (procontroll) in a Java application on OS X.

The problem is in the jinput library. When control gets to net.java.games.input.OSXEnvironmentPlugin's System.loadLibrary call, which looks for "jinput-osx", this call throws an UnsatisfiedLinkError.

I have downloaded the latest jinput libraries from jinput.dev.java.net, discovered the java.library.path for my application by println()'ing it, and put both the jinput.jar and libjinput-osx.jnilib files in this directory.

Does anyone have ideas as to why this library isn't loading or how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

go to Project->Propertity->Java Build Path->Libraries-> JRE->Native Livary->edit:
add the library folder containing jinput-osx as the external folder